# How to calculate the PDF of the 'difference' between two Beta distributions?

Tags: distributions, density-function, monte-carlo, group-differences, beta-distribution

I start with two Beta *distributions*:

$$\mathrm{Beta_A}(p; \alpha_A, \beta_A) = \frac{p^{\alpha_A-1}\,(1-p)^{\beta_A-1}}{\mathrm{B}(\alpha_A, \beta_A)}$$

$$\mathrm{Beta_B}(p; \alpha_B, \beta_B) = \frac{p^{\alpha_B-1}\,(1-p)^{\beta_B-1}}{{\mathrm{B}(\alpha_B, \beta_B)}}$$

where in the context of Bernoulli trials, $\alpha$ can be interpreted as $1 + \mathrm{successes}$ and $\beta$ can be interpreted as $1 + \mathrm{fails}$. $\mathrm{B}$ is the Beta *function*.

I then define the 'difference' between $\mathrm{Beta_A}$ and $\mathrm{Beta_B}$ as:

$$F(x; \alpha_A, \beta_A, \alpha_B, \beta_B) = \mathrm{Beta_A}(p) - \mathrm{Beta_B}(p)$$

**Questions**

- what is the PDF of $F(x)$?
- what family of probability density distributions does $F(x)$ belong to?

**Example and illustration**

For example for $\alpha_A=3, \beta_A=9$ (2 successes from 8 Bernoulli trials) and $\alpha_A=1, \beta_A=5$ (0 successes from 4 Bernoulli trials) the distribution of values that $p$ can take is:

[image: Beta_A and Beta_B]

If I then take $n$ random values $X_A \sim \mathrm{Beta_A}$ and $X_B \sim \mathrm{Beta_B}$, and find the differences between each $i^\mathrm{th}$ element, $X_{A,i} - X_{B,i}$, and plot these $n$ differences in a histogram, I am essentially sampling $F(x)$ - the underlying distribution of $\mathrm{Beta_A} - \mathrm{Beta_B}$ which can only be defined for $x \in [-1,+1]$.

With $n = 5 \times 10^7$ random samples and bin widths of $\Delta x = 0.004$, $F(x)$ takes the following form:

[image: Histogram of sampled differences]

What is the PDF of $F(x)$?

---

**Notes**

- [more verbose version of question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435731/difference-between-two-beta-distributions-is-there-an-exact-joint-probability)
- [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) only gives a scalar value of difference measure

Comment: Do you mean a convolution? https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Fall2010/STP421/lectures/lecture20.pdf

Comment: Would a convolution of $\mathrm{Beta_A} * \mathrm{Beta_B}$ allow me to find probabilities that $p_A < p_B$ or vice versa? - I'm struggling to visualise what the convolution describes from a practical perspective. Also, would it be defined for just $x \in [-1, 1]$? i.e., the 'difference' between $p_A$ and $p_B$ can be no more than 1.0 (i.e., $p_A=1$ and $p_B=0$) and no less than -1 (i.e., $p_A=0$ and $p_B=1$)

Comment: I guess I meant to follow the logic of the derivation but applied to subtraction instead of addition. I don’t think there would be that bound on $x$, though working through the calculus should reveal if there is.

Comment: The notations are awfully confusing, as they make $F(x)$ look like the difference of two Beta densities. Furthermore, $x$ and $p$ are not explicitly related.

Comment: There is an answer on [maths.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1831355/14893).

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'll take a look now. I'm not well-versed in mathematical notation, which is why I used the word "difference" in inverted commas - feel free to correct notation if you think it may help others. Looks like you understood my question in any case, which I'm relieved by.

Comment: [Here are some papers also](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+of+difference+bwtween+two+independent+beta+random+variables&oq=pdf+of+difference+bwtween+two+independent+beta+random+variables&aqs=chrome..69i57.22931j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a bit of an old question but for what it's worth there is an established closed-form solution to this problem, found by [Pham-Gia, Turkkan, and Eng in 1993](https://doi.org/10.1080/03610929308831114). It's a piecewise solution that relies on the [Appell F1 hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Integral_representations). Given
$$
\begin{align}
\theta_1 &= \text{beta}(\alpha_1, \beta_1) \\
\theta_2 &= \text{beta}(\alpha_2, \beta_2) \\
\theta_d &= \theta_0 - \theta_1
\end{align}
$$

Then the probability of the difference of $\theta_d$ is piecewise over $\theta_d$. I've re-written it here, in case you can't access the paper. I'm using $\cdot$ to indicate multiplication when I need to break the equation over several lines.

Given $A = \text{Beta}(\alpha_1, \beta_1)\text{Beta}(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$.

For $-1 \leq \theta_d < 0$:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\theta_d) = &\text{Beta}(\alpha_2, \beta_1)\theta_d^{\beta_1 + \beta_2 - 1}(1 - \theta_d)^{\alpha_2 + \beta_1 - 1} \\
&\cdot F_1(\beta_1, \alpha_1 + \beta_1 + \alpha_2 + \beta_2 - 2, 1 - \alpha_1; \beta_1 + \alpha_2; 1 - \theta_d, 1 - \theta_d^2) \\
&/ A
\end{align}
$$

For $0 < \theta_d \leq 1$:

$$
\begin{align}
p(\theta_d) = &\text{Beta}(\alpha_1, \beta_2)\theta_d^{\beta_1 + \beta_2 - 1}(1 - \theta_d)^{\alpha_1 + \beta_2 - 1} \\
&\cdot F_1(\beta_2, 1 - \alpha_2, \alpha_1 + \beta_1 + \alpha_2 + \beta_2 - 2; \alpha_1 + \beta_2; 1 - \theta_d^2, 1 + \theta_d) \\
&/ A
\end{align}
$$

And for $\theta_d = 0$, $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 > 1$, $\beta_1 + \beta_2 > 1$:
$$
p(\theta_d) = \text{Beta}(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - 1, \beta_1 + \beta_2 -1) / A
$$

As for the family of this distribution, I'm honestly not sure. Somebody else may be able to jump in there.